# How can I extract coefficients from this model in caret?

Tags: r, linear-regression, r-caret, feature-selection

I'm using the caret package with the leaps package to get the number of variables to use in a linear regression.  How do I extract the model with the lowest RMSE that uses mdl$bestTune number of variables? If this can't be done are there functions in other packages you would recommend that allow for loocv of a stepwise linear regression and actually allow me to find the final model?

Below is reproducible code. From it, I can tell from `mdl$bestTune` that the number of variables should be 4 (even though I would have hoped for 3). It seems like I should be able to extract the variables from the third row of `summary(mdl$finalModel)` but I'm not sure how I would do this in a general case and not just this example.

```
library(caret)
set.seed(101)
x <- matrix(rnorm(36*5), nrow=36)
colnames(x) <- paste0("V", 1:5)
y <- 0.2*x[,1] + 0.3*x[,3] + 0.5*x[,4] + rnorm(36) * .0001 
train.control <- trainControl(method="LOOCV")
mdl <- train(x=x, y=y, method="leapSeq", trControl = train.control, trace=FALSE)
coef(mdl$finalModel, as.double(mdl$bestTune))
mdl$bestTune
summary(mdl$finalModel)
mdl$results
```

Here's the context behind my question in case it's of interest.  I have historical monthly returns hundreds of mutual fund. Each fund's returns will be a dependent variable that I'd like to regress against a set of returns on a handful (e.g. 5) factors.  For each fund I want to run a stepwise regression. I expect only 1 to 3 of the five factors to be significant for any fund.

Comment: which part of `summary(mdl$finalModel)` do you need? The table with `V1`, `V2`...columns in it?

Comment: The third row just has `Forced in Forced out` in it, is that really what you want?

Comment: @RonakShah Apologies for not making my question clearer.  How do I extract the model with the lowest RMSE that uses mdl$bestTune number of variables? I will update my question.

Answer (score 2):

you can use:
`coef(mdl$finalModel,unlist(mdl$bestTune))`